# Deploying JAR application with JNLP when JAR contains dependencies(Jars)

Tags: java, web, jar, jnlp

I have an in house Java application that we need to distribute through a web page.  So I compressed the app in a .jar file and included all the dependencies (like miglayout15-swing.jar).  I have about 15 dependencies.

Now I'm wondering if this is the right approach.  Cause when I create my JNLP file and include the resources, it seems to be looking for the jar files outside my main jar file and not inside.

Should the right approach be to put the dependencies in a /lib folder next to where my main app jar is locates?  And the users would be downloading my main jar and all the dependencies separately ?
Here's my JNLP

```
    <resources>
    <java version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="../jsps/Applet/ACFUtility.jar" main="true" />
    <jar href="org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.1.v20130821-1411.jar"/>
    <jar href="swingx-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.6.1.v20130822-1117.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.text_3.5.300.v20130515-1451.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.102.1.v20130827-2048.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.jface_3.9.1.v20130725-1141.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.101.v20130802-1147.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.301.v20130717-1549.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255.jar"/>
    <jar href="org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar"/>
    <jar href="forms-1.3.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="miglayout15-swing.jar"/>
    <jar href="com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar"/>

</resources>
```

[App Jar Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPBYN.jpg)

Comment: *"it seems to be looking for the jar files outside my main jar file and not inside."* Yes. JWS doesn't support loading Jars within Jars. In fact, it would be best to list each extraneous Jar, separately as a free standing Jar, from within a JNLP extension that relates to that API. E.G. a `FormLayout.jnlp`, `JFace.jnlp` or `SWT.jnlp` might be usable in other projects where it just needs to be referenced in the main JNLP as an extension. Saves the user having to download & install extension APIs that have already been (automatically) downloaded for other apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sens. 

So far I’ve made it work by extracting the dependencies with the main jar. 

But I’ll consider separating the jars from the main. 

Thanks again.